# 23984 trailing bytes Error - Redis adaptor with Socket.IO v4

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, node-redis

I'm facing problem when I'm trying to simulate 500+ socket connection with multi container deployment architecture and using Redis adapter. After some time of smooth run I got below error:

```
Error: 23984 trailing bytes
    at Object.decode (/app/node_modules/notepack.io/lib/decode.js:289:11)
    at RedisAdapter.onmessage (/app/node_modules/@socket.io/redis-adapter/dist/index.js:131:34)
    at /app/node_modules/@socket.io/redis-adapter/dist/index.js:84:22
    at PubSub._PubSub_emitPubSubMessage (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/pub-sub.js:294:9)
    at PubSub.handleMessageReply (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/pub-sub.js:237:93)
    at Object.onReply (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/commands-queue.js:40:87)
    at RESP2Decoder.write (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/RESP2/decoder.js:119:26)
    at RedisCommandsQueue.onReplyChunk (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/commands-queue.js:154:72)
    at RedisSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:410:84)
    at RedisSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:201:42)
```

After this error my Socket.IO is unreachable. Can anyone confirm why this issue is coming after some time of smooth run.

Version:

- Socket.io: 4.5.4
- @socket.io/redis-adaptor: 8.0.0
- Redis server: 6.2.6

I have tried to increase `requestTimeout` but it won't work for me and I don't know the exact cause of this issue until now.